# navigation bar doesn't show consistently on different browsers

Tags: javascript, navigationbar, stackblitz

I am having some problems with the navigation bar. On stackblitz it doesnt show on my windows machine with chrome, but it shows on my ubuntu machine with firefox

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-zgajud?file=index.html

EDIT 1:
new link after applying the fix

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-bcjvzq?file=index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links have `type="text / css"`. No spaces there xP `type="text/css"`

Comment: Awesome, I applied the fix. and updated the link, Also why is during the load on top left the body1 or body2 text is appearing before the navigation bar, and navigation bar is appearing a second later. It is not smoothly transitioning during switches from pages